# Any Entity Framework-like ORMs for .NET 2.0? (DB-first!)

Tags: entity-framework, orm, .net-2.0

Because of specifics of my current project, I have to keep using .NET 2.0. Are there any Entity Framework-like ORMs for .NET 2.0?

1. I'm absolutely OK with non-LINQ interface. Syntax like `users.Where(u => u.Age > 100).Count()` is fine.
2. I need to use DB-first approach: I already have a DB with about 30 tables and just considering the ways of simplifying work with it. So, I'd really appreciate if it's possible to generate the required code from existing DB.
3. It's also OK if it won't generate all the required code but provide the way to describe DB structure manually (using attributes, for instance). Basically, I just want to be able to build more or less sophisticated queries without messing with real SQL, `SqlParameter`s and `DataSet`s/`DataTable`s with all these `int.Parse(row[12].ToString())` (that's a legacy code I'm trying to get rid of)
4. Also, that would be great if I'm be able to "override" some particular "queries" with calls to existing stored procedures.

The most important is p.2 - DB first. Is there anything of this kind? Or am I absolutely wrong with my thoughts? Will appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is plenty of available ORMs but some of them are commercial ([LLBLGen Pro](http://www.llblgen.com/defaultgeneric.aspx)). The good choice for you is probably [NHibernate 2.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files/NHibernate/2.1.2GA/) (I think NHibernate 3.x requires .NET 3.5).

You should also thing about moving forward to a newer .NET version. Starting a new development on .NET 2.0 should be avoided and involving a new technology to existing old code base IMO spoils application's architecture and maintainability.

Edit:

> So, I'd really appreciate if it's possible to generate the required code from existing DB.
>
> The most important is p.2 - DB first.

ORM and code generation are two different areas. DB first doesn't mean code generation - it means mapping to existing database without needs to change the database. It is not point of ORM to generate code for you. The point of ORM is to allow you to map DB to classes and abstract querying. If the most important point for you is code generation you should look for something else then ORM. NHibernate doesn't have such code generation included but there are some additional projects which add similar features.

Comment: If code generation is required, LLBLGen Pro is worthy of evaluation. It has a designer and code generator for a variety of ORMs and delivers an experience similar to the Entity Framework designer.

Answer (score 5):

Your best option is to check out [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/). Many (most?) people consider consider it more feature complete and powerful than EF 4.1, plus there are plenty of resources here on stackoverflow and the rest of the web to guide your development process.

Be sure to look into [Fluent NHibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org/) to make mapping from your database to C# objects easy.  The alternative of editing XML files is complex, clunky, and time consuming.

Note that you *might* need to use an older, but still completely functional, version of NHibernate that is compatible with .NET 2.0 (I think, but am not positive, that the more recent versions require .NET 3.5).